# I need help looking for a manhwa with this storyline:

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

From what I remember, the protagonist was reincarnated/got isekai-ed in a novel wherein originally, her mother (or the love interest's mother?) passed away due to stress and pressure from the father's family. The father was quite ignorant and did not notice until it was too late. When the protagonist was reincarnated, things were a bit different though and the father was able to notice the stress the mother was going through. The turning point was when the mother collapsed in the carriage with the leads, who were children at the time. They both confessed their feelings for each other and made up (they both thought the other one didn't have feelings for them because they were in an arranged marriage).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?